# Handle Javascript events from many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I would like to move all Javascript from HTML markup into separate files but I'm still fighting with the following:

Let's say I have a table with many rows (users table) and for every user I need a button to call a function. Now I do this for every row:

```
<button onClick='doSomething(a,b,c);'>Edit</button>
```

I know I can use a class attribute to tell for example jQuery that all the buttons with some class should call a javascript function doSometing. However I don't know how to pass parameters (a,b,c) to that function. These parameters, as I expect, must be on every row in the table, but where to put them?

Just a note: a,b,c are different for every row. Example:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td><button onclick="doSomething(1,3,5);">Work!</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Merry</td>
  <td><button onclick="doSomething(2,7,9);">Work!</button></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: it depends, where exactly are those a,b,c coming from ? if they are let's say stored in some elements in the same row then you can use relative DOM navigation to get to them.

Comment: Why cant you keep function call like the above and function in js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be simply place the values in a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" class="values" value="1,2,3"/>
<input type="button" class="hiddenInput" value="Do it"/>
```

Where each `,` is a value for the function.  In your jQuery click you can use 
`.siblings(.values)`

```
$(".hiddenInput").click(function() {
    var values = $(this).siblings(".values").val().split(',');
    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var c = values[2];
    DoSomething(a, b, c);
});
```

Now if you are using **jQuery 1.4.3 or greater** jQuery will automatically parse `data-*` attributes.  Things become a bunch easier.

```
<input type="button" class="dataAttr" data-values='{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}' value="Do it"/>
```

This allows you to store a value or even a complex json object in this data-* attribute and jQuery will parse it automatically.

```
$(".dataAttr").click(function() {
    var values = $(this).data("values");
    DoSomething(values.a, values.b, values.c);
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zF5eL/)**

Comment: Thanks Mark, this looks cool. I'll use hidden inputs and put JSON objects in the value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on HTML 5 you can use hidden form fields in your page, , and read those out to get the parameters you want..

eg:

```
<button id="something-1" class="something"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-1-param-a" value="1"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-1-param-b" value="42"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-1-param-c"  value="1337"/>

<button id="something-2" class="something"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-2-param-a" value="0"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-2-param-b" value="10"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="something-2-param-c" value="100"/>
```

and in your external JS or script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $(".something").click(function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var a = $("#"+id+"-param-a").val();
   var b = $("#"+id+"-param-b").val();
   var c = $("#"+id+"-param-c").val();
   doSomething(a,b,c);
 });
});</script>
```

*(If you can use HMTML5 you can instead just put them in html data-attributes)*

Comment: This looks good too, but instead of adding input element for every parameter (a,b,c) it would be better to put something like a=1&b=2&c=3 to one input together and split by '&' character.

Answer (score 1):

This trips up a lot of people who are trying to move to unobtrusive JavaScript, but it's an important concept:

**Have your event handlers pull data from the DOM.**

Some of the other answers have already suggested using [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) or hidden fields. These are both good options if you don't want the data to be visible to the user.

Often, though, the data you want is already being used somewhere in the document. Look at this example:

```
<table id="songs">
<tr><th>Song</th><th>Artist</th><th></th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/music/nobodys-fool.mp3">Nobody's Fool</a></td>
    <td>Cinderella</td>
    <td><button class="play">play</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/music/every-rose.mp3">Every Rose Has Its Thorn</a></td>
    <td>Poison</td>
    <td><button class="play">play</button></td>
</tr>
<table>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function playSong(filename, songname, artist) {
    // some code in here that loads the song into a player widget
}

$('#songs button.play').bind('click', function(ev){
  // find the row we belong to
    var songRow = $(this).parent('tr');
    // the file name is in the href
    var file = songRow.find('a').attr('href');
    // the song name is inside the a element
    var song = songRow.find('a').text();
    // the artist is in the second td in the row
    // (index 1 because arrays are numbered from 0)
    var artist = songRow.find('td')[1].text();

    playSong(file, song, artist);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you want, but the simplest would be

```
$('button').click(function(){doSomethind(a,b,c);};
```

Also, read up on this interesting article on [ways to call a function in javascript](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx).

P.S. this is called an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript).

Comment: Khez, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I didn't explain it well. a,b,c are parameters that are different for each row.

Comment: Different how? and where are they pulled from ?

Comment: For example each row may have different all three values. "a" may be user id, "b" and "c" may be another parameters.

Comment: Either post code in your original question or this is outside the scope of your OP.